# Alternating css style when using ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 106%; width: 100%; margin-left: 10px; position: relative; top: -10px">
  <div class="daycol daycolo">
    Mo</div>
  <div class="daycol daycole">
    Di</div>
  <div class="daycol daycolo">
    Mi</div>
  <div class="daycol daycole">
    Do</div>
  <div class="daycol daycolo">
    Sa</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .daycol
  {
    height: 100%;
    width: 19.6%;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgb(215, 230, 238);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .daycolo
  {
    background-color: rgb(215, 230, 238);
  }
  .daycole
  {
    background-color: rgb(147, 182, 202);
  }
```

I would like to create the inner Divs using an ng-repeat if possible but where the class styles alternate. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even`. These directives work exactly as `ngClass`, except they work in conjunction with `ngRepeat` and take effect only on odd (even) rows.

This directive can be applied only within the scope of an `ngRepeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="...">
    <div class="daycol" 
        ng-class-odd="'daycolo'" 
        ng-class-even="'daycole'">
            {{...}}
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, the ng-repeat is in the wrong location. It should be on the second div. I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in css : http://plnkr.co/edit/jMaTWaFGnoXdlX2c2tBY?p=preview

css

```
.daycol {
  background-color:grey;
}
.daycol:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color:#e9e9e9
}
```

html:

```
  <div style="height: 106%; width: 100%; margin-left: 10px; position: relative; top: -10px">
  <div class="daycol ">
    Mo</div>
  <div class="daycol ">
    Di</div>
  <div class="daycol ">
    Mi</div>
  <div class="daycol ">
    Do</div>
  <div class="daycol ">
    Sa</div>
</div>
```